# What are the requirements to setup an SFTP connection in Windows C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ssh, sftp

I am using VS 2012 and I would like to securely transfer files with a server after setting up an SFTP connection. I have heard setting this up in Windows is a big task compared to Linux. Can anyone tell me the exact procedure to follow.

**Developments till now**
As far as I know there are no .NET assemblies which let you do SFTP straight away. But we can use FtpWebRequest using the System.Net assembly.
But I wish to use SFTP. I found an application called freesshd which helps in implementing SSH server. I have also heard about
SFTP Blackbox and Rebex (both of which are paid versions).

**Expected answer pattern**
Step wise walkthrough from how to setup SFTP in a server to how to successfully connect with that server from a local machine.
Suggestions for tools, assemblies or 3rd party libraries which should be used to do this task preferably with link.
Detailed walkthrough on client side and server side modification to achieve this task.

I appreciate any kind of help on this one. Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**: This is for a Windows Form application and not a web application.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy, there's not much to it. You can download the Renci SFTP compiled client from https://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/120565 (both .NET 35 and 40).

On the server side, you already mentioned freeFTPd, which will work fine for testing. Wouldn't recommend it for production level. Add a user and password and home directory. Then start the server listening.

On the client side, using Renci, create a new `StfpClient` object connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 22 using the username and password. For the client to authenticate the server, you can listen to the `client.HostKeyReceived` event.

The only pitfall I've found with Renci is when trying to manually open the stream using `FileMode.Create`. I expected it to overwrite the existing file, but it always appends to the file when uploading. Internally it maintains its own flags, but those flags don't line up with the expected behavior of the `System.IO.FileMode` enum. I was able to truncate the file by uploading an empty `MemoryStream` and then use the `Open` method for Renci. The `Delete` and `DeleteFile` methods didn't seem to work either, which could be a bug in freeFTPd, haven't tested using another SFTP server.